# Simplify a symmetric complex function .

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

Lets consider the following symmetrical complex relation

$f(z) = \frac{B(z)B(\frac{1}{z})}{B(z)B(\frac{1}{z}) + \alpha A(z)A(\frac{1}{z})}$

where $\alpha$ is a real value, $B(z)=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\beta_i z^i$ and $A(z)=\sum_{i=1}^{M}\alpha_i z^i$. I am looking for a function $G(z)$ (as a function of $A$ and $B$) the satisfy the following relation

$f(z) = G(z)G(\frac{1}{z})$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I doubt it, since $$\frac{1}{f(z)}=1+\alpha\frac{A(z)}{B(z)}\frac{A(1/z)}{B(1/z)}$$